# Google Api OAuth in C#, .NET

Tags: c#, .net, oauth, dotnetopenauth, google-oauth

I just want to login to my developed application using Gmail OAuth authentication and there by i need to list out various inputs from it such as

1. First Name
2. Last Name
3. Email Address
4. Dob

Third party which i have used is : DotNetOpenAuth.dll

I have googled and did not find any solution?

Waiting for your valuable comments and suggestions

Answer (score 1):

There is a .NET client library for Google

https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/OAuth2

Answer (score 0):

The DotNetOpenAuth documentation shows how to create an OpenID Relying Party ([using ASP.NET WebForms or MVC](https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth/wiki/Creating-an-openid-relying-party-%28programatically%29)), and [how to extract user attributes from a token](https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth/wiki/Getting-user-attributes) returned from an OAuth IDP.

Comment: Please don't use links as answers.

Comment: The user's question is not easily summarized and requires a fairly lengthy response to answer comprehensively. I am not going to write several page tutorial which others have already written, and written well. Since the OP said they'd already googled and couldn't find an answer, I think providing a link to a post that they missed is entirely acceptable.